# What classical painting depicts a trial or a slavery bidding, where a naked female is standing before a crowd?

Tags: painting

By 'classical' I mean it looked not modern, so it had to be painted at least 100 years ago. I came across that painting in maybe an educational video, but can in no way remember what is was. The mentioned girl or woman is white, and I'm not sure the gathering of other people are all males or have female included.

I was led to wonder what the woman did to deserve that kind of humiliation? My searches led to unfruitful results such as Hypatia - apparently she wasn't in that situation.

Comment: Sorry... Questions about **art history, artwork/artist identification, and art appreciation** are not on-topic for this site; we focus on [questions about making art](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about it. Anyway, could you let it be for a while? I think the answer is near...

Comment: If all it took was a google search... -1

Answer (score 1):

Google search: Classical Painting Slave Market

---

### The Slave Market

Otto Pilny. 1866-1936

[image]

---

### Slave Market in Ancient Rome

Gérôme, Jean-Léon. 1824-1904

[www.hermitagemuseum.org](https://www.hermitagemuseum.org/wps/portal/hermitage/digital-collection/01.+Paintings/37946/)

[image]

---

### The Slave Market

Victor-Julien Giraud. 1867

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Though they aren't what I'm looking for, the 2nd pic "Slave Market in Ancient Rome" by Gerome is quite similar to the mysterious painting. They both show the crowd from behind and the general background tone is red, too. But IIRC there was only 1 girl, she was standing on the left of the pic, and the view is farther so there are more people in the scene. Now that I'm looking at these painting, I'm pretty sure that the mentioned work also depicted a slavery scene.